# MYSQL Stored Procedure cant update within Cursor loop

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

So iv'e been getting into Stored Procedures and iv'e seen people create a cursor and then looping through and doing an UPDATE query on rows, for some reason with my code it gets to the update query and breaks.
Heres the code:

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bump_pro
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE bump_pro(curr_hour INT, curr_minute INT)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur_user_id VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE search_hour VARCHAR(7);
    DECLARE search_min VARCHAR(7);
    DECLARE randBump INT;
    DECLARE newHour INT;
    DECLARE newMinute INT;

    DECLARE get_bump_id CURSOR FOR SELECT user_id FROM bump_iteration;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;


    IF (curr_hour = 0 OR curr_hour = 1) THEN
        SET search_hour = 'hour1';
        SET search_min = 'min1';
    ELSEIF (curr_hour = 6 OR curr_hour = 7) THEN
        SET search_hour = 'hour2';
        SET search_min = 'min2';
    ELSEIF (curr_hour = 12 OR curr_hour = 13) THEN
        SET search_hour = 'hour3';
        SET search_min = 'min3';
    ELSEIF (curr_hour = 18 OR curr_hour = 19) THEN
        SET search_hour = 'hour4';
        SET search_min = 'min4';
    END IF;

    SELECT * FROM bump_iteration;


    SET @select  = CONCAT("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bump_iteration AS (SELECT * FROM bump_table WHERE ", search_hour ," = ", curr_hour ," AND ", search_min ," = ", curr_minute ,");");
    PREPARE stm FROM @select;
    EXECUTE stm;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;

    OPEN get_bump_id;
    addLoop: LOOP
        FETCH get_bump_id INTO cur_user_id;
        IF (done = 1) THEN
            SELECT done as done1;
            LEAVE addLoop;
        END IF;
        /* RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 2 HOURS */
        SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (119-0))+0) INTO randBump;
        IF (curr_hour = 0 OR curr_hour = 1) THEN
            IF (randBump >= 60) THEN
                SET newHour = 1;
                SET newMinute = randBump - 60;
            ELSEIF (randBump < 60) THEN
                SET newHour = 0;
                SET newMinute = 60 - randBump;
            END IF;
        ELSEIF (curr_hour = 6 OR curr_hour = 7) THEN
            IF (randBump >= 60) THEN
                SET newHour = 7;
                SET newMinute = randBump - 60;
            ELSEIF (randBump < 60) THEN
                SET newHour = 6;
                SET newMinute = 60 - randBump;
            END IF;
        ELSEIF (curr_hour = 12 OR curr_hour = 13) THEN
            IF (randBump >= 60) THEN
                SET newHour = 13;
                SET newMinute = randBump - 60;
            ELSEIF (randBump < 60) THEN
                SET newHour = 12;
                SET newMinute = 60 - randBump;
            END IF;
        ELSEIF (curr_hour = 18 OR curr_hour = 19) THEN
            IF (randBump >= 60) THEN
                SET newHour = 19;
                SET newMinute = randBump - 60;
            ELSEIF (randBump < 60) THEN
                SET newHour = 18;
                SET newMinute = 60 - randBump;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SELECT cur_user_id;
        UPDATE bump_table SET hour1 = 1, min1 = 13, bump = 5;
/*
        SET @update  = CONCAT("UPDATE bump_table SET ", search_hour ," = ", newHour ,", ", search_min ," = ", newMinute ,", bump = 4 WHERE user_id = cur_user_id;");
        PREPARE stm FROM @update;
        EXECUTE stm;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;
*/

    END LOOP addLoop;
    CLOSE get_bump_id;
END;
$$
```

As you can see i have a comment with a Prepared Statement in it right before i ended the loop, i tried it but it gave me the same result as trying to update normally, i also tried creating a separate procedure and calling it, but it gave me the same result.

Im looking at examples in "MYSQL Stored Procedure Programming" and other resources on the web and i see people updating within loops, so i'm guessing it is possible.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should usually check your "done" **immediately** after your "fetch"; and your current UPDATE has no `WHERE`. Are you sure your temp table actually has any data?

Comment: @Uueerdo Missed the fetch one since i moved my code around a lot, and a where clause is not always necessary, the current update is for debugging purposes only.

Comment: Wasn't saying WHERE was necessary, just noting the `UPDATE` query's difference. Some questioners are so new, they might somehow think the immediately preceding `SELECT cur_user_id;` would somehow negate the need for one; so I was just covering all bases.